# After renewing letsencrypt SSL certifications, server only returns response code 400

Tags: ssl, webserver, nginx, django

I recently tried to renew my letsencrypt ssl certificate, but once I did that, I’ve been coming down with 400 server responses whenever I try to connect to my website. I’ve tried absolutely everything I can think of. I have attached a copy of my Nginx error log file with the level set to debug, and my server configuration file. Any help is super appreciated.

I'm using Django, Nginx, and Gunicorn on my server.

I ran the command `certbot renew` to renew the cert.

Once that was done, I got nothing but 400 responses.

In addition, when I try to connect to the site, I get a Django error output:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'testing.com,testing.com'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

Report at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'testing.com,testing.com'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
```

It might have something to do with the repeated url, but I'm not sure if that's it either.

Below is my nginx configuration file in sites-available.

```
server { # redirection logic
        listen 80; # port to listen on
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri*;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # listen for HTTPS
    server_name testing.com www.testing.com; # server name to use
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.com/fullchain.pem; # ssl certs
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dt-testing.com/privkey.pem;   
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; } # site icon to use
    location /static/ { # location of static files
        root /websites/DT/path/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/websites/DT/run/gunicorn.sock; # connector to gunicorn
    #error_page 405 =200 $uri;
    }

    rewrite_log on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log debug;
}
```

Here is my nginx debug log output.

```
"GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: testing.com
Host: testing.com
X-Real-IP: 185.252.151.5
X-Forwarded-For: 185.252.151.5
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Nexus 6P Build/NOF27C) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.81 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept-Language: en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Charset: utf-8,ISO-8859-1;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: x-gzip, gzip, deflate

"
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http cleanup add: 000055DF21463240
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 get rr peer, try: 1
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 stream socket 15
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 epoll add connection: fd:15 ev:80002005
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 connect to unix:/websites/DT/run/gunicorn.sock, fd:15 #13
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 connected
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream connect: 0
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 posix_memalign: 000055DF2142F410:128 @16
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream send request
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream send request body
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 chain writer buf fl:1 s:524
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 chain writer in: 000055DF214F97D0
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 writev: 524 of 524
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 event timer add: 15: 60000:4664042409
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http finalize request: -4, "/?" a:1, c:2
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http request count:2 blk:0
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http run request: "/?"
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/"
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/04/06 00:02:56 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream dummy handler
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http upstream process header
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 malloc: 000055DF21502980:4096
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 recv: eof:1, avail:1
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 recv: fd:15 160 of 4096
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http proxy status 400 "400 Bad Request"
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http proxy header: "Server: gunicorn/19.9.0"
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http proxy header: "Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2019 00:02:57 GMT"
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html"
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 http proxy header done
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 xslt filter header
2019/04/06 00:02:57 [debug] 11579#11579: *12 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.15.5 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2019 00:02:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

EDIT: At this point, I think that I'm doubling the url somewhere. I have also provided my nginx.conf file in the hope that I'm doubling something in there.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}



http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: *"I’ve tried absolutely everything I can think of."* - Which says nothing about what you actually tried and is thus totally useless information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not seem to be directly related to SSL but it looks more like you are using a broken HTTP client which sends multiple HTTP `Host` fields. This is plain wrong and totally against the HTTP standard:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: testing.com
Host: testing.com
...
```

These multiple `Host` fields are concatenated together and given to the web application, which rightly complains about the header which makes no sense:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'dt-testing.com,dt-testing.com'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

This will likely lead to the `400 Bad Request`.

To fix the problem you need to fix your broken HTTP client. I have no idea what client this is but since no modern client will use `HTTP/1.0` (all use at least `HTTP/1.1`) and no modern client will accept the compression `x-gzip` (see `Accept-Encoding` field) I suggest this is some self-made client and not the  client it claims to be in the `User-Agent` field.

Comment: where would I find the configuration for this client or the client at all? From what you're saying, it sounds more like the problem is not on the server side.

Comment: could it be caused by the lines         proxy_set_header Host $host;
        include proxy_params;?

Comment: @Max: The configuration of the client has nothing to do with the server configuration. I have no idea what client you are using.  And in my opinion `proxy_set_header Host $host;` should not cause the duplicate `Host` header - but you might try to skip it. As for `include proxy_params;` - I have no idea what's in this file so I cannot say if this is relevant.